# Short story about "assembly robot"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for the author and title of a story about a man at a remote outpost in space, who spends a lot of time assembling "flat pack" machines that are delivered to him. To save time, he orders a robot to perform the assembly. When it arrives, it also requires assembly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like the super-short (just 350 words!) story by Isaac Asimov entitled "[Insert knob A in hole B](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62724)". It has two men at a remote outpost instead of one, but otherwise follows the question closely. It was written while Asimov was attending a TV panel show, which is why it is so short (and also why it contains a grammatical error). The plot summary from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_Knob_A_in_Hole_B) reads:

> Two men on a remote space station receive all of their equipment from
> Earth unassembled, and must assemble it with only vague and confusing
> instructions ("composed by an idiot", one says); as a result, it often
> fails to work properly or at all. They eagerly await the arrival of a
> sophisticated positronic robot that will repair existing equipment and
> assemble new ones.
>
> Upon its arrival, they discover that the robot has been shipped in 500
> pieces with vague, confusing assembly instructions.

Comment: That's the one, thanks!